# Useful college minor for an aspiring UX Designer?

Tags: ux-field, career-development

So, currently, I planned on minoring in just general Business (don't exactly know why I did that...). I know what kind of degree you have doesn't matter as much as experience does in UX but, for someone who wants to go into the UX field, what do you think would be a useful minor to have? I am probably going to stick with something that involves business because I have already taken a few business courses and don't want them to be a waste. So, saying that, are there any business-y minors that could be useful to UX Designers as well?

Comment: What's your major? In the end, if you're specifically wanting to get into UX, then you likely want to pursue a degree program with some direct bearing on that.

Comment: I'm majoring in Informatics(which is basically all about applying technology to solve problems) with a focus on Human Centered Computing. So, I've been taking like HCI and Interaction Design classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marketing is actually really similar to UX and if they have a lot of group work that might be helpful. Management might be another useful one for the communication aspects.

Personally, I wouldn't bother with the minor at all, ESPECIALLY if you can graduate faster. Just take courses that are useful. Such as:

Design courses
Sketching courses
Public speaking/presenting courses
Programing courses

Comment: Marketing is often diametrically opposed to UX. :)

Comment: I thought about Marketing but, after thinking about it more, I don't think I am going to bother with a minor. I'm trying to graduate as fast as possible haha. Like you said, I decided I'm just going to take courses I think are useful. Like a couple Graphic Design and Digital Art classes.